# How to set directive dynamically by data from $scope in angular-ui-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Sorry my english is poor ... Don't laugh, please...

In compile, I can't use $scope.
When I set directive (For example, 'ui-grid-selection') by hard code, It works perfectlly like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W5Nk.png)

In link, when I set attribute 'ui-grid-selection' only, it doesn't work.
When I set `attr` and write `$compile($element.find('.mygrid'))($scope)`, it works but only the function is correct, it's layout became like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pccfV.png)  and the console log shows:

```
    Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/ngTransclude/orphan?p0=%3Cdiv%20ng-transclude%3D%22%22%3E
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
    at Ia.link (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:239:272)
    at Z (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:70:149)
    at I (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:59:255)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:335)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:352)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:50:444
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:52:322
    at h (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:322) <div ng-transclude="">
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$compile/ctreq?p0=uiGrid&p1=uiGridHeaderCell
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
    at M (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:127)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:193
    at r (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at M (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:170)
    at I (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:59:104)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:335)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:50:444
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:52:322
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$compile/ctreq?p0=uiGrid&p1=uiGridRow
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
    at M (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:127)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:193
    at r (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at M (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:170)
    at I (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:59:104)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:335)
    at I (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:59:199)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:335)
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$compile/ctreq?p0=uiGrid&p1=uiGridRow
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
    at M (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:127)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:193
    at r (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at M (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:170)
    at I (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:59:104)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:335)
    at I (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:59:199)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:335)
```

I don't know how to fix it.Sad me,  Help please ...

Here my controller's code:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('mainCtrl',
  ['$scope', '$q', '$http', 'uiGridTreeViewConstants', function ($scope, $q, $http, uiGridTreeViewConstants) {

  $scope.gridOptions1 = {
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
    }
  };

  $http.get('demo/data/uigrid_100.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.gridOptions1 = data.gridOptions;
    $scope.gridEnable1 = data.gridEnable;
    $scope.gridOptions1.data = data.gridData;
  });

}]);

app.directive('jsonUiGrid', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template:
      '<div>' +
        '<div ui-grid="options" class="mygrid"></div>' +
      '</div>'
    ,
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      options: '=?',
      enablesData: '=enables'
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs){
      $scope.$watch('enablesData', function(newValue) {
        if (typeof(newValue) != 'undefined'){
          if(newValue && newValue.length){
            angular.forEach(newValue, function(attr){
              $element.find('.mygrid').attr(attr, '');
            });
            $compile($element.find('.mygrid'))($scope);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried get data by using $http before run mainCtrl, And Inject into mainCtrl. It works!!

The detail is. I'm using a template named "Clip-Two_130", it contains a function in "config.router.js" which is named "loadSequence".

```
function loadSequence() {
    var _args = arguments;
    return {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q',
        function ($ocLL, $q) {
            var promise = $q.when(1);
            for (var i = 0, len = _args.length; i < len; i++) {
                promise = promiseThen(_args[i]);
            }
            return promise;

            function promiseThen(_arg) {
                if (typeof _arg == 'function')
                    return promise.then(_arg);
                else
                    return promise.then(function () {
                        var nowLoad = requiredData(_arg);
                        if (!nowLoad)
                            return $.error('Route resolve: Bad resource name [' + _arg + ']');
                        return $ocLL.load(nowLoad);
                    });
            }

            function requiredData(name) {
                if (jsRequires.modules)
                    for (var m in jsRequires.modules)
                        if (jsRequires.modules[m].name && jsRequires.modules[m].name === name)
                            return jsRequires.modules[m];
                return jsRequires.scripts && jsRequires.scripts[name];
            }
        }]
    };
}
```

And I set router like:

```
.state('app.demo_ui-grid2', {
    url: "/demo_ui-grid2",
    templateUrl: "demo/views/demo_ui-grid2.html",
    //resolve: loadSequence('ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'demoUiGridCtrl2'),
    resolve: {
        deps: loadSequence('ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'demoUiGridCtrl2').deps,
        options: function($q, $http){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('demo/data/uigrid_options.json').then(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data.data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    },
    controller: 'mainCtrl',
    title: 'demo_ui-grid2',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'demo ui-grid2'
    }
})
```

The controller file has been modified to :

```
    'use strict';


app.controller('mainCtrl',
  ['$scope', '$q', '$http', 'options', 'uiGridConstants', 'uiGridData',
      function ($scope, $q, $http, options, uiGridConstants, uiGridData) {

  // Bind grid enable
  $scope.gridEnable1 = options.gridEnable;

  // Bind grid options
  $scope.gridOptions1 = options.gridOptions;
  $scope.gridOptions1.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
    $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
  };

  // Bind grid data [NO NECESSARY]
  //$scope.gridOptions1.data = data;

  $scope.url = [
    'demo/data/100.json',
    'demo/data/500_complex.json'
  ];


  $scope.changeData = function(url){
    var promise = uiGridData.get(url);
    promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.gridOptions1.data = data;
    }, function(data) {
        console.log('changeData ERROR');
    });
  }

}]);


app.factory('uiGridData', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
  return {
    get: function(url) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.reject(data);
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    } // end get
  };
}]);


app.directive('jsonUiGrid', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template:
      '<div>' +
        '<div ui-grid="options" class="mygrid"></div>' +
      '</div>'
    ,
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      options: '=?',
      enablesData: '=enables'
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs){
      angular.forEach($scope.enablesData, function(attr){
        $element.find('.mygrid').attr(attr, '');
      })

      $element.html($element.html());
      $compile($element.contents())($scope);
    }
  }
}])
```

Maybe I can only modify the controller file without modifying in router file?

Wish there's a better solution. Still need help.

The data file you can use:

[100.json](http://ui-grid.info/data/100.json)

[500_complex.json](http://ui-grid.info/data/500_complex.json)